# Как сохранить в памяти и суммировать в число определенную в байтах массу файлов а затем использовать результат?

Tags: c++

Есть кусок кода, который выполняется в цикле перебора файлов и определяет вес в байтах каждого файла.

```
void mass(char filePath[]) {

fstream file(filePath, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

if (!file) {
    return;
}

file.seekg(0, ios::end);
unsigned fileSize = file.tellg();
file.seekg(ios::beg);
file.close();

// тут как то нужно записывать в память значение fileSize и суммировать все значения, обновляя итоговый результат в памяти
```

}

.
.
.

void endSumm() {

```
std::string buf;
string summ_mass = ""; // тут как то получить результат общего веса файлов из памяти, преобразовать в строку
return summ_mass;
```

}

Как сохранить в памяти и суммировать в число определенную в байтах массу файлов а затем использовать результат?
Я только начал осваивать C++ и нужна ваша профессиональная помощь.
Спасибо!

Comment: Не проще пройтись, не открывая сами файлы, по каталогу чем-то типа `findfirst/findnext`?

Comment: может и проще, если бы знал) но я только учусь... не подскажете как это сделать?.. но исходя из готового кода возможно как то решить задачку?

Comment: используется winapi (уже включен заголовок windows.h), а функции findfirst/findnext требуют подключения нового заголовка dir.h

Comment: вам же нужно список имен файлов передать  в функцию... Я что то не понимаю?

Comment: список имен мне не нужен... Нужно подсчитывать вес файлов (fileSize) пока происходит обход каталогов. Затем вывести полученную сумму байтов в строку (summ_mass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного улучшим вашу функцию и вернем строковое представление размера файла.

```
std::ifstream::pos_type mass(const const std::string& filePath) {   
    ifstream file(filePath.c_str(), std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    return file.tellg();    
}
```

Эту же функцию можно написать и по другому.  В стандартной  библиотеке есть `struct stat` и функкция  `stat` принимающий указатель на обьект этой структуры. Этот обьект после вызова функции(которая и проверяет и выдает обьекту все данные) может вернуть размер файла через свой метод.

```
long long
mass(const const std::string& filePath) 
{
    struct stat buf;
    int k = stat(filePath.c_str(), &buf);
    return (k == 0 ? buf.st_size : 0);
}
```

Я предпочел бы этот вариант.

Теперь храните резульат функции где хотите:

```
long long m = mass("file1");
m += mass("file2");
m += mass("file3");
// ...
string summ_mass = std::to_string(m);
```

**Важно:** Если хотите хранить результат функции, то возвращайте из нее то, что хотите хранить (или же передайте в функцию ссыльку(указатель) на этот обьект).

Comment: вам нужна сумма этих значений или строка, где записаны все эти значения? Если нужна сумма  всех размеров, тогда зачем  нужна строка?

Comment: Верно, мне нужно получить сумму всех значений (вес всех обойденных файлов), а вывод в строку нужен после - просто я отправляю в дальнейшем строковое значение на сервер.

Comment: а если файлы будут большие по весу, ваша функция сможет нормально работать?

Comment: Я немного поправил, чтобы не было вопросов и проблем.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!